# Function to determine if a string contains characters only from another

Tags: javascript, string, validation, arrays

I'm working on a validation function for html input tags. I've the string of the value of the particular input and the string containing the allowed characters.

```
var allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var value = element.value;
```

I'd like to write a function to determine if the `value` contains character only from the `allowed` string. I'm looking for a straight-forward and simple solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: 2 words: [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Match any pattern you can imagine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can use regex

```
function alphanumeric(inputtxt)  
{   
    var letters = /^[a-z]+$/;  
    //if you want upper and numbers too 
    //letters = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    //if you only want some letters
    // letters = /^[azertyuiop]+$/;
    if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))  
    {  
        alert('Your registration number have accepted : you can try another');  
        document.form1.text1.focus();  
        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert('Please input alphanumeric characters only');  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: the `allowed` string can be anything (e.g. 'aeiou', etc) and is a parameter of my `validate(allowed, value)` function, thus I wouldn't like to use regex in this way. Could you please give me a regular expression based on the string. So I would use regex if I could make a regex of the string...

Comment: yes you can just have 'aeiou' using this regex: /^[aeiou]+$/ and you can export your string in your regex var string = "aeiou"; var reg = /^[+string+]$/

Answer (score 0):

Use below function.

```
function isChar(str) {
  return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str);
}
var allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
if(isChar(allowed )){
    alert('a-z cool :)');
}else{
    alert('Enter only Char between a-z');
}
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xmDNb/)

Comment: Please see my comment above on @ant's anwser.

Comment: @gen check new demo http://jsfiddle.net/xmDNb/4/.
I don't think result can achieve without add Regx in allowed variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer without the use of regex

```
function allLetter(inputtxt)
{
    var inputtxt_low = inputtxt.toLowerCase();
    inputtxt_low = inputtxt_low.split('');
    var alpha_arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ];
    var count;
    for(count = 0; count < inputtxt_low.length; count++)
    {
        if(alpha_arr.indexOf(inputtxt_low[count]) == -1)
        {
            inputtxt= '';
            break;
        }
    }
    return inputtxt;
}
```