# Verifying for only a-z and A-Z characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get my javascript file to validate input "name". I have a regex for the allowed characters set as `/^[A-Za-z]+$/`.

However, whenever the function gets to the verification of the characters, it does not show anything at all. I have been following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339036/function-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-characters-only-from-another) but it still does not work. Here is my code:

```
function validateForm(){
   message = validateName();
   window.alert(message);
}

function validateName(){
    name = document.forms["supportForm"]["name"].value;
    allowedChars = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(name.value.match(allowedChars))
    {
        error = "You're Cool!";
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `allowedChars.test(name)`

Comment: Did you mistakenly took  `value` two times? first in `name` assignment and then in `if` ?

Comment: `name = input.value`, `name.value`. I think there are too many `value`s.

Comment: triply downvoted - what a community of haters

Comment: Not haters, merely people following the guideline that "the question does not show any research effort". "Research effort" would definitely include "debugging". In this case, merely stopping the program at the `name =` line, and examining `name`, then stopping it again at the `if (` line and examining `name.value` would have easily revealed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var name` is already the defined value of `document.forms["supportForm"]["name"].value;`
You then use `name.value`, which doesn't make sense. As you're trying to get a sub value in a variable. Instead you want `name.match(allowedChars)`
Also I suggest you use `console.log` to test your inputs for bugfixing.

```
function validateForm(){
   message = validateName();
   window.alert(message);
}

function validateName() {
    name = document.forms["supportForm"]["name"].value;
    console.log(name); //So you know it's picking up the value
    allowedChars = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(name.match(allowedChars)) {
        error = "You're Cool!";
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When referencing a variable in which an attribute has already been referenced, you do not need to reference the attribute again.

The attribute `value` is referenced in `document.forms["supportForm"]["name"].value;` and in `if(name.value.match(allowedChars))`

The proper way to handle this would be :

```
function validateForm(){
   message = validateName();
   window.alert(message);
}

function validateName(){
    name = document.forms["supportForm"]["name"].value;
    allowedChars = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(name.match(allowedChars))
    {
        error = "You're Cool!";
        alert(error);
    }
}
```